# Drawing a very large zoomable, pannable content over tiles (UIViews) : iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

What would be the best way to draw a large zoomable, pannable content across tiles (UIViews)? I cannot use [CATiledLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) because there will be parts of the content which will be only visible on zooming in after a certain zoom level (as in maps). The content I am drawing is a large graph (bars, line etc) which will be dynamically rendered based on the graph data provided.

From Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)
 It looks like you should use tiling and avoid creating very large views. I am using this approach to tile the views which works pretty good : [Tiling](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1342)
Now the difficult part is to determine what content goes over a particular tile(say tile(r,c) at *r-th* row and *c-th* column). One solution I tried is to draw the whole content for every tile and transform it based on tile's position but this is turning out to be very slow and jittery as the user scrolls.

What would be a faster way to determine the content for a particular tile using the above approach? (This relates to how Apple is doing it for providing the content for CATiledLayer)
OR
 Is there any alternative approach I can consider to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on a mac app where the contents of the view may not fit in RAM.

First of all, you definitely want to use `UIScrollView`. Getting scrolling right is extremely complicated, do not try to roll it yourself unless you're prepared to write a hundred thousand lines of code.

Embed a UIView subclass inside a scroll view, and monitor the scroll view for changes to the visible area (and zoom level).

Whenever the visible area changes, add/remove CALayer objects from the view accordingly.

The complication is you cannot update layers while the user is scrolling, it will be too slow. So wait for the user to stop scrolling, then update the layers. And have enough layers visible in the area just outside the visible bounds so the user doesn't notice.

Here's how I handle delayed updates:

```
- (void)userDidScroll
{
  // wait until the user has stopped scrolling, then process scroll
  static NSDate *lastScrollDate = nil;
  lastScrollDate = [NSDate date];
  NSDate *thisScrollDate = lastScrollDate.copy;

  double delayInSeconds = 1.0; // how long after the scroll should we update?
  dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
  dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    if (thisScrollDate != lastScrollDate)
      return;
    lastScrollDate = nil;

    [self updateLayer];
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Abhi, so what I am right now doing is implementing the drawing on the background thread as explained in [WWDC 2012 session 211](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) so that scroll is smooth. Determining the tile content will take some time but it will be on the background thread. I am very positive about the approach. Will post my solution if it works well